# Petites politesses à vélo

Tags: politesse, exclamations

Je fais du vélo sur une voie verte (un ancien chemin de halage), large de deux mètres, qui est partagée avec les piétons (des familles, des chiens, des joggeurs).

À mon avis, d'après le code la route, ce sont les piétons qui ont toujours la priorité : c'est à moi de les éviter.

Ceci se passe à la campagne -- normalement on dit bonjour à tout les gens que l'on croise.

Quand je les double, je n'ai pas beaucoup de temps pour leur parler (puisque je roule, sauf si je m'arrête), donc je cherche des formules de politesses brèves.

Que dire dans les situations suivantes :

- ils n'ont pas entendu ma sonnette, et je suis donc arrivé et j'ai ralenti assez près derrière eux ? Par exemple, bonjour, pardon, excusez-moi;
- ils se mettent de côté et me disent pardon ? Par exemple, bonjour, merci, ou de rien;
- ma sonnette a l'air de leur avoir fait peur, ils sursautent en l'entendant ? Par exemple, merci, pardon, excusez-moi, ou bonjour.

Je veux surtout leur laisser avec l'impression qu'ils ont le droit d'être sur le chemin, que l'on peut en être content et que ce n'est pas de leur faute si j'ai eu à ralentir.

De plus, y a-t-il aussi une formule pour avertir quelqu'un (surtout un autre cycliste) que je vais le doubler à sa gauche ou à sa droite ? Je crois qu'on dit, par exemple, en anglais, "*On your left!*" ou "*On your right!*".

Comment: Cette question me semble mieux destinée au StackExchange pour les compétences interpersonnelles, mais je ne sais pas si on y parle français ...

Comment: J'imagine que non, malheureusement, et de même le site pour le cyclisme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: *Excusez-moi*.

2: (*Bonjour*) *merci* (*bonne journée*).

3: *Excusez-moi* ou *désolé*.

Pour avertir de son arrivée, on peut reprendre l'expression *chaud devant* utilisée en cuisine/restauration mais elle ne précise pas le côté qui sera emprunté.

Comment: Dans le deuxième cas, est ce que "merci" est bien une bonne réponse à leur "pardon"? Mon instinct est de leur expliquer qu'ils ne m'ont pas agressé, et que donc ils n'ont aucun besoin à me demander pardon. Dans le premier cas, pouvez-vous m'expliquer, pourquoi préférez-vous *Excusez-moi* au lieu de *Pardon*? Est-ce que *Pardon* est un mot qui se dit tout seul, comme une demande? Et dans le troisième cas, si je pouvais ajouter quelques mots à *désolé*, quels mots seraient-ils?

Comment: *Merci* n'est pas une réponse à *pardon* mais au fait qu'ils se soient rangés sur le côté. Le fait de ne pas répondre au pardon indique qu'il n'y a avait pas lieu de le faire. On peut éventuellement répondre *c'est moi !* pour *c'est moi qui vous demande pardon*. Dans le premier cas, on aurait pu dire *pardon* mais j'ai la sensation que l'on force plus le passage dans ce cas alors qu'avec *excusez-moi*, on laisse plus de choix aux personnes dérangées. Pour le cas n° 3, on peut dire *désolé, je suis confus* puis *bonne journée* avec un grand sourire...

Answer (score 2):

Dans le contexte d’une balade à vélo, je pars du principe que les interventions les plus courtes sont les meilleures, pour favoriser la clarté du message. J’éviterais donc les « excusez-moi » et autres formules trop longues.

Si la vitesse de pédalage permet d’être entendu correctement, il est cependant possible d’ajouter, dans la plupart des cas, un « bonne journée ! » (ou tout autre variante comprenant le moment précis de la journée) final.

Pour les cas précis :

1. > ils n'ont pas entendu ma sonnette

   **« pardon »** quand je suis juste derrière les personnes, et « merci » si elles se sont décalées pour que je les double.
2. > ils se mettent de côté et me disent pardon ?

   **« merci »** : même s’il ne met pas d’emphase particulière sur le fait qu’ils ont le droit d’être sur le chemin, cela reste une marque de gratitude claire, qui se démarque du silence de nombreuses personnes.
3. > ma sonnette a l'air de leur avoir fait peur, ils sursautent en l'entendant ?

   **« Désolé », suivi d’un « merci »** s’ils se décalent ensuite.

Concernant le sens de passage, celui-ci ne me semble s’appliquer que lorsque la différence de vitesse est grande entre vélo et piéton, et qu’il y a risque de collision. La politesse est donc généralement plus légèrement en retrait, et on entend régulièrement **« Droite ! »** et **« Gauche ! »**.
 Il reste quand même possible de les modérer de cette façon : **« Attention à [direction] ! »**.